# Check if a class is inconsistent in Konclude

Tags: owl, reasoning, reasoner

I'm using Konclude reasoner .I know inconsistent Classes are shown in red in Protégé .How can I check if a class is Inconsistent in Konclude?

Comment: just check if the class is subclass of `owl:Nothing`

Comment: @UninformedUser There is  no way to check if a Class is a Subclass of any other class .its a reasoner so I supposed there is but I didn't find any way.

Comment: why not? I also don'T know how you use Konclude at all. Which API do you use? Anyways, they even provide a CLI command to check if a single class is satisifiable: https://github.com/konclude/Konclude#usage - so why aren't you following the documentation?

Comment: @UninformedUser yeah they provide a way to check if a single class is satisfiable but not consistent. And I'm using the command line directly.

Comment: a class being "inconsistent" is the same as being "unsatisfiable" - all it means is that a class can't have any instances, otherwise the whole ontology would be logically inconsistent which in fact means one could infer anything from it.

Comment: @UninformedUser I have an ontology where a class turns red in Protege (unconsistant) but Konclude returns it as satisfiable..